# How to box a trait that has generic type parameters?

Tags: rust

I am generally able to use a trait as the type parameter for something like Box<>:

```rust
trait CtxVal {}
type CtxNodes = HashMap<String, Box<CtxVal>>;
```

But when the trait has it's own generic type parameters, like [PartialEq](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/cmp/trait.PartialEq.html), I'm stuck.

```
type CtxNodes = HashMap<String, Box<PartialEq>>;
```

I get the error:

```
main.rs:6:37: 6:46 error: the type parameter `Rhs` must be explicitly specified in an 
      object type because its default value `Self` references the type `Self`                             
main.rs:6 type CtxNodes = HashMap<String, Box<PartialEq>>;                                                                                                                                
                                              ^~~~~~~~~
```

If I were to provide the type for the `PartialEq`, what would that even be?

```rust
Box<PartialEq<???>>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify what you want the object to be able to be compared equal to:

```
fn foo(value: Box<PartialEq<u8>>) -> bool {
    *value == 42
}

fn bar(value: Box<PartialEq<&str>>) -> bool {
    *value == "the answer"
}
```

Comment: Mmmkay. I thought there was more to it, since `Box<SomeTrait>` doesn't really specify an actual "type" like `Box<SomeStruct>` would or even `Box<SomeGenericStruct<SomeType>>`. Hoping there was some magic there for boxing generic traits. But I can see how the parameterizing of the trait changes things.